# How to solve this recurrence function with substition method?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, substitution, recurrence

I have a very strange function which looks like this:

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n* log2(n)

I need to solve this with the substitution method, but I haven't been able to reach any decisive answer.

I need solution steps and big-O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When facing `log`, change like `n = 2^k` (`k = log2(n)`) is often a way out:

```
n = 2^k
```

So we have

```
T(2^k) = 2 * T(2^(k - 1)) + k * 2^k
```

Let's see what does it mean:

```
T(2^k) = 2 * T(2^(k - 1)) + k * 2^k =
       = 2 * (2 * T(2^(k - 2)) + (k - 1) * 2^(k - 1)) + k * 2^k =
       = 4 * T(2^(k - 2)) + (k - 1) * 2^k + k * 2^k =
       = 4 * (2 * T(2^(k - 3)) + (k - 2) * 2^(k - 2)) + (k - 1) * 2^k + k * 2^k = 
       = 8 * T(2^(k - 3)) + (k - 2) * 2^k + (k - 1) * 2^k + k * 2^k = 
         ...
       = 2^k * T(0) + 2^k + 2 * 2^k + ... + k * 2^k =
       = 2^k * T(0) + 2^k (1 + 2 + ... + k) =
       = 2^k * T(0) + 2^k * k * (k + 1) / 2 =
       = 2^k * (T(0) + k * (k + 1) / 2)
```

Time to return to `n`, `n = log2(k)`:

```
T(n) = n * (T(0) + log2(n) * (log2(n) + 1) / 2)
```

In term of `O(n)` we have

```
O(T(n)) = O(n * (T(0) + log2(n) * (log2(n) + 1) / 2)) =
        = O(n * (const + log2(n)^2 / 2 + log2(n) / 2) =
        = O(n * log2(n)^2 / 2) =
        = O(n * log2(n)^2) =
        = O(n * log(n)^2)
```

So, the answer is

```
O(T(n)) = O(n * log(n)^2)
```

Note, that since `log2(n) == log(n, b) / log(2, b)` for arbitrary base `b > 1` we can use `log(n)` instead of `log2(n)`

Comment: This is great. I have reached this point as well but since we are using the substitution method we made an assumption that n = 2^k and I believe we need to prove it for T(2^k+1) for the complete solution.

Comment: @ammar albakri: technically, yu can *rewrite* all these formulae for `T(n + 1) == T(2^(k + 1))`, but why shuld you do it? We have solved the general case, we've found `T(n)`, if one's interesting in `n + 1` (s)he can put `n + 1` into formulae